# Guidelines for writing "use cases" in Manifest for Android foreground service type "special use"?

Tags: android, foreground-service

Android 14 has made it compulsory to declare a *proper* foreground service type for foreground services. Details [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#fgs-types).

Three new foreground types have been introduced, of which [`specialUse`](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#special-use) is one. It covers all the cases that cannot be categorized into the other types. As per the docs, we are needed to mention "use cases" in the Manifest itself using the following:

```xml
<service android:name="fooService" android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse">
  <property android:name="android.app.PROPERTY_SPECIAL_USE_FGS_SUBTYPE" android:value="foo"/>
</service>
```

As per the docs, this will be reviewed when the app is uploaded on Google Play.

Are there any guidelines for writing the "use cases" (i.e. inside `android:value="foo"`)? Or can I just describe what my service does in my own words?

Comment: Wanted to mention that I wrote a long paragraph in the Manifest describing what each foreground service does. Google Play accepted it in the production release.

Comment: Hey, I've done this, but Android 14 device not triggering service callback. Android 13 and below working fine. Did you have to request user permission for `specialUse`?